# Unexpected coinbasevalue in regtest mode

Tags: bitcoind, regtest

Running a simple local setup with 3 nodes in regtest mode.  Getblocktemplate tells me the coinbasevalue = 25 bitcoins but the block height is only 202.  Shouldn't the coinbasevalue = 50 bitcoins?

Comment: What base software did you use, please, some more details!

Comment: Running the latest version of bitcoind (0.9.2.1) on linux.  Have three local nodes in regtest mode connected to each other. Block height = 202.  Maybe the block reward is based on the actual current block reward and not my local block height?

Answer (score 3):

In regtest mode, the block reward halves every 150 blocks instead of every 210000 blocks. See the consensus.nSubsidyHalvingInterval settings in chainparams.cpp.